# Can a custom function type be variadic?

Tags: go, variadic-functions

I have this custom function type MyFuncType that accepts a single argument of type MyStruct:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  SomeVar string
}

type MyFuncType func(MyStruct)

var fn MyFuncType
fn = func(ms MyStruct) {//...}
```

Then I thought I could change the definition of MyFuncType to pass additional arguments:

```
type MyFuncType func(MyStruct, ...interface{})

var fn MyFuncType
fn = func(ms MyStruct, suffix string, anythigIWant int) {//...}
```

Now the compiler complains about incompatible type for fn. Ok, I think I can understand that a variable number of arguments can not define a function signature...
But even with the definition below:

```
type MyFuncType func(MyStruct, interface{})
```

It's the same song.
Finally it is not possible to use interface{} as [any]type for an argument in a custom function type or am I missing something here?

My workaround is to attach the implementation of functions of type MyFuncType to a struct which provides additional required data.

Comment: The problem isn't the variadic, it's that the signatures don't match. They have to be identical in terms of number, order, and types of arguments and returns (only the names are irrelevant).

Comment: In other words, a variadic function signature only applies to another variadic function, not a function with any number of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is the func signature, you need to define it exactly as it is in the `type`, and then you can use it sending whatever you want:

```golang
type MyFuncType func(MyStruct, ...interface{})

var fn MyFuncType
fn = func(ms MyStruct, args...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(ms.SomeVar, args[0], args[1])
}

// Using it as if the signature was:
// func(ms MyStruct, suffix string, anythigIWant int)
fn(MyStruct{SomeVar: "some var"}, "suffix", 123)
```

Check it out: https://play.golang.org/p/R_qZoul9AcV